# Silverlight FTP file upload not work in server

Tags: silverlight

I have create a file upload project in silverlight 
using FtpClient by following this link
(https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp).

It works well in local development(visual studio) and local 
iis server also.But when I host this into my server i get following problem.

**var success = ftpClient.BasicConnect();**

**success becomes false**.What may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am the author of this library.

Did you read the [`README`](https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp#configure-your-silverlight-application-properly) file? It explains the steps:

> You need to follow [this awesome tutorial](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx) to enable elevated trust in-browser, which is needed for socket-programming.

So, my guesses:

- Missing signing/Missing reg-entry for the CA
- or missing policy-file